# Äquivalent zu »seitlich« für oben und unten

Tags: single-word-request

Bringt man an einem Ding links und rechts weitere Sachen an, so sind diese seitlich angebracht.

Gibt es ein Wort wie *seitlich,* nur für oben und unten?

Gesucht ist ein einzelnes Wort, keine Umschreibung (wie ober-/unterhalb).

Comment: Ober -oder unterhalb ist keine Umschreibung. Oder irre ich mich da?

Comment: Soweit ich weiß, gibt es kein Wort, dass äquivalent zu *seitlich* ist, also wirst du wohl oder übel mit *ober-* bzw. *unterhalb* leben müssen ;)

Comment: Ich kenne aus dem Handwerken die Ansage "mach über Ende einen Strich", was soviel heißt wie "am Ende der Latte muss abgeschnitten werden, da muss der Strich hin". Ich finde nur spontan nichts dergleichen. Mal schauen. Generell taugt dies aber nicht als äquivalent zu *seitlich*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Die richtigen Antworten sind:

Oben:

> darüber
>   oberhalb

Unten:

> darunter
>   unterhalb

Da die Richtung der Schwerkraft ständig wahrnehmbar ist, hat sie auch starke Auswirkung auf unsere Sprache. Die absoluten Richtungen (Norden, Süden usw.), in die links und rechts weisen, ändern sich ständig, wenn wir uns bewegen. Oben bleibt aber immer oben, und unten immer unten. Daher verwechseln manche von uns gerne mal links und rechts, aber niemals oben und unten. Und aus demselben Grund gibt es das Wort „seitlich“, das sowohl „links“ als auch „rechts“ bedeuten kann, aber kein Wort, das zugleich „oberhalb“ und „unterhalb“ bedeutet. („Vertikal“ passt noch am ehesten, wird aber anderes verwendet als „seitlich“.)

Es gibt noch mehr Richtungen:

vorne:

> davor

hinten:

> dahinter

Auch vorne und hinten kann man nicht verwechseln, weil vorne immer da ist, wo wir gerade hinschauen, und hinten auf der anderen Seite ist. Auch für diese Richtung gibt es kein Äquivalent zu „seitlich“, nicht einmal so etwas wie „vertikal“.

---

Es gibt aber auch Sprachen, in denen Richtungen nicht, wie bei uns, relativ zum Standpunkt des Betrachters angegeben werden, sondern absolut:

> nördlich
>   östlich
>   südlich
>   westlich

(Wer eine dieser Sprachen spricht, muss jederzeit genau wissen, wo Norden ist, was starke Auswirkungen auf die räumliche Wahrnehmung hat.)

Comment: *außerhalb* ist das Gegenteil von "innerhalb" und kann "seitlich", "oberhalb", "davor" usw. bedeuten.

Comment: Der Punkt geht an dich ;)

Comment: +1 für Hinweis auf Aboriginee-Sprachen

Comment: Die Begründung ist origninell aber keineswegs einleuchtend. Ich kann beim Pferd seitlich Satteltaschen befestigen. Meine Schwester hat am Hollandrad vorne und hinten einen Korb - hier wäre ein zusammenfassendes Wort ebenso praktisch. Was hat das mit Verwechselbarkeit zu tun? Gar nichts.

Comment: @userunknown Es geht hier darum, daß wir aus den genannten Gründen einen viel deutlicheren Unterschied zwischen vorn und hinten sowie oben und unten wahrnehmen als zwischen links und rechts. Deshalb verwechseln wir letztere häufiger, und aus demselben Grund hat ein Wort, das beide ohne Unterscheidung zusammenfaßt, mehr Nutzen als eines für eines der beiden anderen Paare.

Comment: @Matthias: Das ist ein an den Haaren herbeigezogener Unfug. Die Leute verwechseln gar nicht rechts und links, sondern nur die Begriffe dafür, soweit ich weiß. Und es ist eine kleine Minderheit die das tut - für den Rest, der auch spricht, schreibt, hört und liest trifft das Argument also nicht zu. Wenn man an der nächsten Kreuzung links abbiegen muss, dann hilft es auch wenig wenn jemand sagt "an der nächsten Kreuzung zur Seite fahren".

Comment: Die Entstehung der Begrifflichkeit hat wohl eher damit zu tun, dass (um beim Pferd zu bleiben) es normalerweise vollkommen egal ist, ob du die Satteltasche rechts oder links hinhängst, aber sehr wohl von Bedeutung, ob du den Sattel oben oder unten dranmachst. Von daher halte ich Huberts Begründung schon für schlüssig.

Answer (score 9):

Als Ergänzung und zur Antwort von @HubertSölnast, dass man "*davor* und *dahinter* nicht verwechseln könne. Unter Umständen kann man davor und dahinter nämlich schon verwechseln.

Beispiel: Man fährt in einem Auto und der Beifahrer weist den Fahrer an: "Parken Sie hinter dem Auto da vorne."

Jetzt ist es eine Frage des Bezugssystems, ob man erst an dem Auto vorbei fährt und dann parkt, oder ob man *nicht* an dem Auto vorbei fährt, sondern hinter dem Heck des parkenden Auto parkt. Bei dem einen setzt man das parkende Auto als Ursprung des Bezugssystems, im anderen Falle das eigene Auto.

Answer (score 4):

Ich fürchte, Du wirst um "oben und unten" oder "oben bzw. unten" nicht herumkommen.

Wenn ich Dich richtig verstehe, geht es Dir konkret um den Fall, dass irgendetwas *an* dem "Ding" befestigt ist, nicht dass es sich darüber oder darunter befindet.

Dann scheiden ober- und unterhalb auch gleich mal aus, da sie Deinen Fall nicht abdecken. Wenn etwas "oberhalb" des "Dings" angebracht ist, befindet es sich "darüber", also "höher als", und ist nicht "oben daran befestigt".

("Seitlich" funktioniert in beiden Fällen.)

Answer (score 1):

Auf einem anderen Niveau (auch im übertragenen Sinn gut verwendbar) oder Stockwerk (wenn es sich um eine Gebäude handelt) oder Höhe/Tiefe (Berge bzw. beim Tauchen).

Answer (score 1):

Ein vergleichbares Wort gibt es nicht, und als Ergänzung zur Argumentation von @HubertSchölnast möchte ich die Hypothese aufstellen, daß in unserem Alltag Gegenstände mit Links-Rechts- oder Rotationssymmetrie (mit vertikaler Achse) sehr viel häufiger vorkommen als solche, bei denen Vorder- und Rückseite oder Ober- und Unterseite ähnlich sind, und daß es aus diesem Grunde nützlicher ist, ein Wort zu haben, das einfach nur "an der Seite" bedeutet als eines, das die (eben häufig verschiedenen) Vorder- und Rück- oder Ober- und Unterseiten in einen Topf wirft.

In den seltenen Fällen, in denen die Ober- und Unterseite eines Gegenstandes als die einzigen relevanten Seiten wahrgenommen werden (z.B. Tischplatten oder Regalbretter), kann man mit **beidseitig** ein Wort benutzen, das dann "oben und unten" bedeutet. Man beachte, daß das Wort selbst keine Information über die Ausrichtung beinhaltet. Angewandt auf bedrucktes Papier meint es "vorn und hinten".

Comment: It is an addendum to another answer - to the degree that it does not attempt to answer the question at all. As such, it is a very long comment and Not An Answer. 35 minutes ago you were very keen about deleting a NAA post. How about starting with this one?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Der zweite Absatz ist sehr wohl ein eigenständiger Versuch, die Frage zu beantworten.

Comment: Ganz ehrlich: Ich habe keinen Bock mich mit dir auf diesem Niveau zu streiten. Wenn du meinst, http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22602/differences-between-types-of-schorle#22605 wäre keine Antwort, dann unternimm doch die notwendigen Schritte. Aber nörgle nicht wegen einer alten Sache rum.

Answer (score 1):

Auch wenn der Thread sehr veraltet ist:

oben:

> obig ( Bedeutung: oben erwähnt, genannt ("die obige Beschreibung"))

unten:
genau dafür suche ich gerade das äquivalent und bin daher hier gelandet. Habe bisher leider nichts gefunden.

Answer (score 1):

Was du suchst, ist meiner Meinung nach "vertikal zu". Das kann nur drüber oder drunter sein.

Answer (score 0):

Man könnte auf der Erde **polar** riesige Gewinde anbringen, so dass es vom Weltall aussieht, als sei sie Teil eines Globus, aber habe die Halterung verloren.

Je nach Lage (besser: Stand) einer Batterie würde *polar* dort auch Sinn ergeben können, und man könnte versuchen, dieses *polar* metaphorisch auf weitere Objekte zu übertragen. Ob dies immer verstanden wird, bleibt zu bezweifeln, insbesondere wenn, wie bei Batterie oder Magnet, andere Bedeutungen von polar verstanden werden können.

> Um einer Billardkugel einen Mitläufer- oder Rückläufereffet mitzugeben, muss diese möglichst polar getroffen werden.

Vollkommen abseitig scheint mir meine Idee nicht. :)

Answer (score 0):

ich stehe gerade vor einem ähnlichen Problem, bei dem ich das Wort ***obenseitig*** genutzt habe (im Sinne von: obenseitig montierter Ventilator an einer Anlage). Da es mir selber komisch vorkam, habe ich es mal gesucht und wirklich oft findet man es nicht. Auf auf der Seite des Duden konnte ich es nicht finden. Einige Patentschriften nutzen das Wort hingegen.

Vielleicht hilft’s ja.

Answer (score -1):

Ich bin überzeugt, dass "Enden" die horizontale Form der "Seiten" am besten beschreibt.
z.B. "Die Markierungen waren endlich angebracht." im Gegensatz zu "Die Markierungen waren seitlich angebracht."
Genau so könnte man endwärts wie seitwärts gebrauchten.
Als Wortspiel: Wenn man eine Saite (!) kürzt, erzeugt man neue Enden, nicht aber neue Seiten.
Interessant wird es aber bei einem Quader, bei dem man sowohl Seiten (l/r) als auch Enden (o/u) und Vorder- und Hinterflächen hat. Wie nennt man dann diese? Seiten, Enden und ... Fronten? (Man spricht ja auch von einer "Rückfront" für die Rück- oder Hinterseite eines Objekts.)

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Schöner als neue selbst ausgedachte Wortschöpfungen wären Veweise auf bestehende Wörter mit bestehenden Einträgen in (Online-)Lexika. Heißt ja nicht, dass die eigene Idee deswegen völlig falsch ist - nur dass German.SE dazu dient, möglichst faktenorientiert zu antworten.