# Differences between types of Schorle

Tags: meaning, word-choice, difference

I am well aware of the fact that "Schorle" is translated as 'spritzer' in English. Then what is the difference between Schorle and Weinschorle?
Secondly, how would 'Orangenschorle' be translated as - is it carbonated orange juice? Is this the same with "Apfelschorle"?

Thanks in advance

*(Some may criticise this question for having multiple questions within, but they are all extremely intertwined and all that I'm asking for is the differences between the types of Schorle.)*

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schorle

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I'm sorry, I don't speak German :(

Comment: Really? It is »spritzer« in english? I didn't know that. It is funny because »Spritzer« is the word that is used in Austria. Never say »Schorle« in Austria. Say »Spritzer« or »Gespritzter«.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: To complete (?) this listing, it's my impression that "(Saft-)Schorle" is also rather unknown in Northern Germany, whereas the rather straightforward construction "Apfelsaft mit Sprudel", "Orangensaft mit Sprudel", etc. is also quite widespread in various regions in Germany.

Comment: @Turbo, the German wikipedia article de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schorle  has an english version, too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spritzer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two "standard" types of Schorle, you might translate "Schorle" as "mixed with carbonated water".

- **Saftschorle**
  Consist of the choosen type of juice with sparkling (carbonated) water. The juice-to-water ratio in restaurants is somewhere between 1:1 and 1:2, pre-mixed schorle is usually around 50-60% juice. The naming follows the pattern [fruit] (saft) [schorle], the (saft)-bit is optional.
- **Weinschorle**
  Follows the same principle as for juice, but may - at least in SW Germany* - be mixed with sparkling lemonade (sweet) instead of carbonated water, which gives four options for mixing and naming:

  - Weißweinschorle or *Schorle weiß-sauer* *
  - Rotweinschorle or *Schorle rot-sauer* *
  - *Schorle weiß-süß* *
  - *Schorle rot-süß* *

*The variations with the asterisks are not common everywhere in Germany, you might have to specify how to mix them when ordering.

Comment: The ratio range is wider in my experience. Some people go stronger than 1:1 while others prefer a refreshing 1:3. As for Weinschorle, I have drunk everything from "just a shot of white wine for the taste" (a great refreshing drink in the summer) to "just a shot of water for good conscience" (Pfälzer Weinfest). The basic premise of "juice or wine with sparkling water" is probably all the word "Schorle" gives you.

Comment: In northern Germany "Weinschorle" is, to my knowledge, always with sparkling water too.

Answer (score 7):

I think that Stephie's answer is correct if you are talking about German German (The kind of German that is spoken in Germany). In Austrian German the word »Schorle« is widely unknown. It isn't even listed in the official dictionary for Austrian German (Österreichisches Wörterbuch, ÖWB).

So here is an addendum to Stephies answer, and it deals only with Austrian German:

The german verb »spritzen« can be translated as: squirt, splash, spatter, sprinkle and also inject. So when you put ("inject") soda water into wine, this is also called »spritzen«, so the resulting drink is called ...

> Ein gespritzer Wein

The short form of this is

> Ein Gespritzer

or even shorter

> Ein Spritzer

The mayor of Vienna, Michael Häupl, is know for using an alternative Term for this drink:

> Ein Spritzwein

see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgfdnAMSGRM In this 3-Second-Video he says: »Man bringe den Spritzwein« (*You bring the spritzer*)

If you want to be more specific, you can say if you want white wine or (not so common) red wine mixed with soda water:

> Ein weißer Spritzer = White wine mixed with water
>   Ein roter Spritzer = Red wine mixed with water (just a theoretical possibility. I never saw this in real life)

Also well known, but somewhat outdated is ...

> Eine Mischung
>   eine weiße Mischung

This literally just means »a mixture« or »a white mixture«.

All the above terms refer to a mixture of wine and water.

---

When you mix a softdrink like coke or some juice with water, then this is:

> Ein aufgespritzes Cola = half coke, half water
>   Ein aufgespritzer Apfelsaft = half apple juice, half water
>   Ein gespritzer Apfelsaft = the same

Keep in mind, that soft drinks are female in Germany, but neuter in Austria, so in Austria is correct »ein aufgespritzes Cola« or »das aufgespritze Cola« (»eine aufgespritze Cola« would be wrong in Austria, and since I believe that »aufgespritzt« is not used in Germany, it might be wrong there too)

If you mix soft drinks with water, the word »aufgespritzt« is more common than »gespritzt«. If you mix juices with water, »gespritzt« is more common.

---

But you also might mix wine with some softdrink or juice. This is called:

> Ein süßer Spritzer
>   Eine süße Mischung

or, a more specific example:

> Ein Almdudler-Spritzer

Almdudler is a very popular soft drink in Austria. It tastes similar to ginger ale, and is very often used to mix with beer and wine. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almdudler

Also possible:

> Ein Almdudler weiß = Almdudler mixed with white wine
>   Ein Cola rot = Coke mixed with red wine

Comment: +1 Incredibly well-researched and detailed answer

Comment: +1 except that I've met (south) Germans who also say "das Cola" (shudder)  ;)

Comment: I am sure that this answers a question, now I just have to find out which.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: As I wrote in the 2nd paragraph: This is an addendum to another answer, because Stephies Answer was true only for German German (without pointing out this restriction). She/he (sorry, I don't know Stephies gender) left out the fact, that the word *Schorle* simply would not be understood in other German speaking regions, namely in Austria.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Why this *shudder*? I also don't like to hear German German articles like »die Cola« or »das Gummi« or »das Spray«, but I never would say or write something like *shudder*. In Austria it is »das Cola«, »der Gummi« and »der Spray«. I don't *shudder* to German Immigrants who live in Austria since decades and don't learn the language of the country where they are living now, and so still use wrong articles. So why do you shudder when you hear Austria German? »Das Cola« is **NOT WRONG**! It is just another standard variation of German language. Not better, but also not worse!

Comment: No use trying to teach Them who think they can write as they speak, but we know better ;-)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Yes, it is an addendum to another answer - to the degree that it does not attempt to answer the question at all. As such, it is a very long comment and Not An Answer. The questions was about the meaning of a certain word and how to translate it. It is completely irrelevant whether this word would be understood in Austria or not. Recently you were very keen about deleting a NAA post. How about starting with this one?

Comment: I have never heard of anyone here in Germany mixing coke with water. If the water is added as ice cubes and then starts melting, all right - but adding liquid water upfront? Seems unusual to me.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Als ich noch in Graz studiert habe, bin ich viel Rad gefahren und habe vor allem im Sommer, am Ende einer Radtour, nachdem ich viel Flüssigkeit ausgeschwitzt hatte, gerne mal ein aufgespritztes Cola getrunken, und anschließend gleich ein zweites (zu je 0,5 Liter, insgesamt also 1 Liter).